# Polynomial Class in Java problems

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble with this polynomial class, specifically the checkZero and differentiate methods. The checkZero class is supposed to see if there are any leading coefficients in the polynomial, and if so, it should resize the coefficient array. The differentiate method should find the derivative of a polynomial, but I keep getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` errors.

```
public class Polynomial {

    private float[] coefficients;
    public static void main (String[] args){
        float[] fa = {3, 2, 4};
        Polynomial test = new Polynomial(fa);

    }

    public Polynomial() {
        coefficients = new float[1];
        coefficients[0] = 0;
    }

    public Polynomial(int degree) {
        coefficients = new float[degree+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
            coefficients[i] = 0;
    }


    public Polynomial(float[] a) {
        coefficients = new float[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            coefficients[i] = a[i];
    }

    public int getDegree() {
        return coefficients.length-1;
    }

    public float getCoefficient(int i) {
        return coefficients[i];
    }

    public void setCoefficient(int i, float value) {
        coefficients[i] = value;
    }

    public Polynomial add(Polynomial p) {
        int n = getDegree();
        int m = p.getDegree();
        Polynomial result = new Polynomial(Polynomial.max(n, m));
        int i;

            for (i = 0; i <= Polynomial.min(n, m); i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i] + p.getCoefficient(i));
            if (i <= n) {
                //we have to copy the remaining coefficients from this object
                for ( ; i <= n; i++) 
                    result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i]);
            } else {
                // we have to copy the remaining coefficients from p
                for ( ; i <= m; i++) 
                    result.setCoefficient(i, p.getCoefficient(i));
            }
        return result;
    }

    public void displayPolynomial () {
        for (int i=0; i < coefficients.length; i++)
            System.out.print(" "+coefficients[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static int max (int n, int m) {
        if (n > m)
            return n;
        return m;
    }

    private static int min (int n, int m) {
        if (n > m)
            return m;
        return n;
    }

    public Polynomial multiplyCon (double c){
        int n = getDegree();
        Polynomial results = new Polynomial(n);
        for (int i =0; i <= n; i++){ // can work when multiplying only 1 coefficient
            results.setCoefficient(i, (float)(coefficients[i] * c)); // errors ArrayIndexOutOfBounds for setCoefficient
           }

        return results;
       }

    public Polynomial multiplyPoly (Polynomial p){
        int n = getDegree();
        int m = p.getDegree();
        Polynomial result = null;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
            Polynomial tmpResult = p.multiByConstantWithDegree(coefficients[i], i); //Calls new method
            if (result == null){
                result = tmpResult;
            } else {
                result = result.add(tmpResult);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void checkZero(){

        int newDegree = getDegree();
        int length = coefficients.length;
        float testArray[] = coefficients;

        for (int i = coefficients.length-1; i>0; i--){
            if (coefficients[i] != 0){
                testArray[i] = coefficients[i];

            } 
            }
        for (int j = 0; j < testArray.length; j++){
            coefficients[j] = testArray[j];
        }
    }    

    public Polynomial differentiate(){

        int n = getDegree();
        int newPolyDegree = n - 1;
        Polynomial newResult = new Polynomial();

        if (n == 0){
            newResult.setCoefficient(0, 0);
        }

        for (int i =0; i<= n; i++){
            newResult.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i+1] * (i+1));
        }
        return newResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Haven't you asked this question here before?

Comment: you've posted WAY too much code.  the exception should tell you exactly which line is the problem, post that part and expand if necessary.  Better yet, use a debugger and step through your code.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more problems, but one is a problem with your differentiate method:

```
    int n = getDegree();
    ...
    Polynomial newResult = new Polynomial();
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        newResult.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i + 1] * (i + 1));  //This line
    }
```

Your paramaterless constructor initializes an array with length 1, so "newResult" will only have 1 index, and you try to put something into place i, which goes above 1 if the Polynomial you are in have an array of greater length than 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, a few code notes:

New arrays are automatically initialized to 0 in Java. This is not needed.

```
    coefficients = new float[degree+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        coefficients[i] = 0;
```

I also see many lines which might become more readable and compact if you use the trinary operator, for example:

```
int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= Polynomial.min(n, m); i++) 
            result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i] + p.getCoefficient(i));
        if (i <= n) {
            //we have to copy the remaining coefficients from this object
            for ( ; i <= n; i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i]);
        } else {
            // we have to copy the remaining coefficients from p
            for ( ; i <= m; i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, p.getCoefficient(i));
        }
```

Could become something like

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= result.getDegree(); i++) 
            result.setCoefficient(i, 
              i>n?0:coefficients[i] + 
              i>m?0:p.getCoefficient(i));
```

The one bug I did spot was here:

```
int n = getDegree();
....
for (int i =0; i<= n; i++){
        newResult.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i+1] * (i+1));
    }
```

This will always call coefficients[coefficients.length] on the last iteration, which will always fail.

The stack trace of the exception when you ran this program should tell you exactly where the error is, by the way.